# Mulesoft Dataweave: Flatten a JSON to create database records

Tags: json, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I work with Mule 4, DataWeave 2.3.
I want to flatten a JSON object. Every key in the JSON should be in the key of the new record object. When the JSON has nested objects/arrays then the keys are concatenated with a ".".
So it is prepared to insert it into a database table as a record without losing the keynames of the original JSON.
This is my incoming JSON message:

```
{
  "supplierId": "123456",
  "targets": {
    "test": "JustAtest"
  },
  "assets": [
    {
      "id": "1229782",
      "serialNumber": "120007324",
      "name": "Machine A",
      "gpsPostition": {
        "longitude": 12.234,
        "Latitude": 45.12
      },
      "used": [
        {
          "startTime": "2023-12-12T08:08:00.345Z",
          "KWH": 234
        },
        {
          "startTime": "2023-12-13T08:08:00.372Z",
          "KWH": 240
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1229781",
      "serialNumber": "120007323",
      "name": "Machine B1",
      "gpsPostition": {
        "longitude": 18.229,
        "Latitude": 123.487
      },
      "used": [
        {
          "startTime": "2023-12-14T10:15:00.231Z",
          "KWH": "220"
        },
        {
          "startTime": "2023-12-15T10:15:00.117Z",
          "KWH": "154"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This should be the result:

```
var ExpectedResult = [
    {"supplierId." : "123456"},
    {"targets.test." : "JustAtest"},
    {"assets.id." : "1229782"},
    {"assets.serialNumber." : "120007324"},
    {"assets.name.": "Machine A"},
    {"assets.gpsPostion.longitude.": 12.234},
    {"assets.gpsPostion.latitude.": 45.12},
    {"assets.used.startTime.": "2023-12-12T08:08:00.345Z"},
    {"assets.used.KWH.": 234},
    {"assets.used.startTime.": "2023-12-13T08:08:00.372Z"},
    {"assets.used.KWH.": 240},
    {"assets.id." : "1229781"},
    {"assets.serialNumber." : "120007323"},
    {"assets.name.": "Machine B1"},
    {"assets.gpsPostion.longitude.": 18.229},
    {"assets.gpsPostion.latitude.": 123.487},
    {"assets.used.startTime.": "2023-12-14T10:15:00.231Z"},
    {"assets.used.KWH.": 220},
    {"assets.used.startTime.": "2023-12-15T10:15:00.117Z"},
    {"assets.used.KWH.": 154}
]
```

This is what I have tried:

```
fun testMe(mesg1: Any, prefix, newRecords: Any) = do {
    fun createDbsRecord(mesg: Any, prefix) = do {
    var pre = if(prefix == null) "" else prefix ++ "."
    ---
    mesg  match {
        case mesg is Object -> mesg mapObject((value,key,index) -> createDbsRecord(value, (pre) ++ (key)))
        case [x ~ xs] -> mesg map ($ mapObject((value,key,index) -> createDbsRecord(value, (pre) ++ (key))))
        //case mesg is Array -> mesg map ($ mapObject((value,key,index) -> createDbsRecord(value, (pre) ++ key)))
        else -> (newRecords << {(pre): (mesg)}) 
        }
    }
    ---
    createDbsRecord(mesg1, null)    
}

output application/json
---
//mesg is the incoming JSON message
testMe(mesg, null, [])
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Cannot coerce Array ([{"supplierId.": "123456"}]) to Object

120|         case mesg is Object -> mesg mapObject((value,key,index) -> createDbsRecord(value, (pre) ++ (key)))
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What I notice in debugging is that the newRecords Array seems not te be filled with new objects(records). And also the mesg1 array is not destructed. Objects are not removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the excellent method from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77606606/721855) you can get the expected result. I had to add support for arrays and remove their indexes assuming all numeric keys are indexes. I didn't add the dot at the end of the keys by default. You can uncomment a line to get it.

```js
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Tree
import isNumeric from dw::core::Strings

fun collectLeaves(data) =
  if ((data is Object) == false)
    data
  else
    data mapObject ((value, key, index) -> value match {
        case value is Object -> collectLeaves(value)
        case value is Array -> value reduce ((item, accumulator = {}) -> accumulator ++ collectLeaves(item))
        else -> 
          (key): value

      })

fun objToProperties(obj) =
  (obj pluck ((value, key, index) -> 
    (key): value
  ))
var aggregatedKeys = payload mapLeafValues (value, path) -> {
  (path.selector 
    filter (!isNumeric($)) // removed array indexes
    joinBy "." 
    // ++ "." // uncomment if you want a dot at the end of the key
  ):
  value
}
output application/json  
---
collectLeaves(aggregatedKeys)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "supplierId": "123456",
  "targets.test": "JustAtest",
  "assets.id": "1229782",
  "assets.serialNumber": "120007324",
  "assets.name": "Machine A",
  "assets.gpsPostition.longitude": 12.234,
  "assets.gpsPostition.Latitude": 45.12,
  "assets.used.startTime": "2023-12-12T08:08:00.345Z",
  "assets.used.KWH": 234,
  "assets.used.startTime": "2023-12-13T08:08:00.372Z",
  "assets.used.KWH": 240,
  "assets.id": "1229781",
  "assets.serialNumber": "120007323",
  "assets.name": "Machine B1",
  "assets.gpsPostition.longitude": 18.229,
  "assets.gpsPostition.Latitude": 123.487,
  "assets.used.startTime": "2023-12-14T10:15:00.231Z",
  "assets.used.KWH": "220",
  "assets.used.startTime": "2023-12-15T10:15:00.117Z",
  "assets.used.KWH": "154"
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much aled ones again!!  It is exactly doing what I want.  Great function the mapLeafValues in the Util:tree.

Comment: The metit belongs to the user who posted the other question I linked. I adapted it for a different output format.